# Only select items where a table contains two specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(journey.id)
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
JOIN pattern_link ON pattern_link.section = pattern.section
WHERE pattern.service = :service AND pattern.direction = :direction AND journey_day.day = :day
```

Above I have a MySQL query that should pull out a list of journeys based on some variables.

What I want to do now is add another two variables which can adjust the query. I need to convert what I'm about to say into SQL format and then append it to my current query but I'm not sure how to do so.

I need to ensure that the `pattern_link` table contains **both** a `:departure` and `:arrival` value, essentially making it only pull journeys that contain these two variables.

In this example we're talking about bus timetables, so, in theory I only want to select journeys that travel through both the `:departure` and `:arrival` bus stops. The `pattern_link` table is essentially a table that connects bus stop to bus stop on a journey. Also, it's worth saying that I don't mean just these two stops, I mean that these two stops are somewhere in the table.

How can I do this?

Comment: It might help to see your schema.

Comment: As @cdhowie said, please show your table schema and some sample data, and the desired result. What columns should `:departure` and `:arrival` be in?

Comment: Sorry guys, please bear with me 2 minutes whilst I export the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand how you have phrased the question.  I think, though, that you are looking for journeys that contain both a departure and arrival value in corresponding `pattern_link`s.  If so, you can do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT j.id
FROM journey j JOIN
     journey_day jd
     ON jd.journey = j.id JOIN
     pattern p
     ON p.id = j.pattern JOIN
     pattern_link pl
     ON pl.section = pattern.section
WHERE p.service = :service AND p.direction = :direction AND jd.day = :day
GROUP BY j.id
HAVING sum(p.busstop = :arrival) > 0 and
       sum(p.busstop = :departure) > 0;
```

I'm not sure if the fields you want are in the `pattern` table or the `pattern_link`, but the same idea would hold.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to add the additional condition would be to create a self-join, as below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(journey.id)
FROM journey
JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
JOIN pattern_link pattern_link_dep ON pattern_link_dep.section = pattern.section AND pattern_link_dep.<time_column> = :departure
JOIN pattern_link pattern_link_arr ON pattern_link_arr.section = pattern.section AND pattern_link_arr.<time_column> = :arrival
WHERE pattern.service = :service AND pattern.direction = :direction AND journey_day.day = :day;
```

Replace the `time_column` with the appropriate column name.

Comment: So just to clarify, this would essentially ensure that only journeys containing both the departure stop and arrival stop would be selected (in the pattern_link tables as you've done)?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It would be interesting to see some data. You might want to create suitable indexes on the tables.

Comment: Depending on the data, you might need to self-join with another instance of the `pattern` table as well, but without seeing some data, I am not able to tell for certain.

Answer (score 0):

Just and a where clause to restrict the pattern and then use a group by/having clause to get a count of 2.

```
AND (:departure = pattern_link.some_column OR :arrival = pattern_link.some_column)
```

That should get you down to two records in the jounrney.  Then group by journey.id and check the count:

```
GROUP BY JOURNEY.ID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Let me know if this doesn't work, or if the table can hold a departure or arrival twice and get a count greater than one by having two rows with the given departure and none of the arrival for instance.